# How to execute terminal command in specific directory from java

Tags: java

I am trying to execute originate command in specific directory "/usr/local/freeswitch/bin", In bin I have to run executable file fs_cli by ./fs_cli command, In fs_cli I have to execute following command

```
originate loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789)
```

Its working fine from terminal, The same command can be executed from bin

```
./fs_cli -x "originate loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789)"
```

I tried folowing java program to do the above task

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./fs_cli -x \"originate loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789@192.168.0.198)\"");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String str = null;
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

I have creted symbolic link of fs_cli and placed in current location
The above program is showing following output

**Output**

-ERR "originate Command not found!

As far as I am concerned whwn above command is working fine with terminal it should be the same from java, So it shows I am wrong somewhere 
Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: why don't you fully path it or does /usr/local/freeswitch/bin/fs_cli not work?

Answer (score 5):

Use `ProcessBuilder` and supply a `directory` path

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
        "./fs_cli",
        "-x",
        "originate loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789@192.168.0.198)");
pb.directory(new File("..."));
Process pr = pb.start();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
String str = null;
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Where possible, you should provide the command arguments as separate `String`s, this will pass each as a separate argument to the process and take care of those arguments that need to be escaped by quotes for you (unless it's expecting the quotes, then you should include them anyway)

Comment: Thank u sooooo much, I am really very exited. I was working on this from past 6 days now it has come to end

Answer (score 1):

The other way is:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /usr/local/freeswitch/bin && ./fs_cli -x \"originate loopback/1234/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789)\"" );
processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: Thank u sooooo much, I am really very exited. I was working on this from past 6 days now it has come to end